# KeyError - but the key is there

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using a `notebook` in [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/what-is-azure-databricks#:%7E:text=Azure%20Databricks%20is%20a%20data,Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20services%20platform.&text=For%20a%20big%20data%20pipeline,Event%20Hub%2C%20or%20IoT%20Hub.).

**Question**: In the following code, the key `ProductName` exists but I am getting the error shown below. What could be a reason for this error and how can we resolve it? I tried some online suggestions but still no luck.

```
KeyError: ProductName

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
```

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd

def fn_myFunction(prodname):
  prod_name = prodname.replace('(','')
  prod_name = prod_name.replace(')','')
  prod_name = prod_name.strip()
  return prod_name 

data_df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/myDataFile.txt', sep='~\*', engine='python', quotechar='"', header='infer')
data_df['ProductName'] = data_df['ProductName'].apply(lambda x: fn_myFunction(x))
.............
```

Comment: Is Databricks actually relevant to the problem? I'm not familiar with it, but everything else here looks like normal Pandas stuff.

Comment: Is that the full traceback? I ask because it doesn't include any of your code. It looks like the error is happening at `data_df['ProductName']` on the RHS of the assignment, which would mean that the column simply doesn't exist and you're mistaken. Please make a [mre].

Comment: Check `data_df.columns` to see if the column is actually there.

Comment: Do you want function applied to column or df? See a column solution below. Happy to edit to df

Answer (score 1):

I dont have AzureDatabricks open. I tried this in my databricks community pyspark and it works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=spark.createDataFrame([
  ('123abc' ,  '(type 1)'   ,  1 ),
('456def' ,  'type 1 ' ,   1),
('789ghi'  , 'type 2'   , 0),
('101jkl' ,  'type 3'   ,  0)
  
],

('id'    ,   'category' , 'flag'))

df= df1.toPandas()
```

function

```
def fn_myFunction(col):
  col = col.str.replace('\(','', regex=True)
  col = col.str.replace('\)','', regex=True)
  col = col.str.strip()
  return col
```

Solution

```
df['category'] = fn_myFunction(df['category'])
```

Output

```
     id category  flag
0  123abc   type 1     1
1  456def   type 1     1
2  789ghi   type 2     0
3  101jkl   type 3     0
```